# Create react app not working, file already exists with EEXIST error

Tags: reactjs, macos, terminal

I'm trying to install React for the first time and I'm getting the following error from my terminal:

```
~ % npm install -g create-react-app
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /Users/shibazhussain/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/12/7c
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/shibazhussain/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/12/7c'
npm ERR! File exists: /Users/shibazhussain/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/12/7c
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/shibazhussain/.npm/_logs/2024-03-29T16_46_46_875Z-debug-0.log
shibazhussain@Shibazs-MacBook-Air ~ %
```

I tried the following so far:

1. Using the clear cache command
2. tried using npx instead of npm
3. tried to uninstall react app before installing
4. tried a $(whoami) / sudo chown command
5. --force overwrite

Comment: I found the solution, I pasted this entire line into my terminal and now it works:

npm uninstall -g create-react-app && npm i -g npm@latest && sudo npm cache clean -f && npx create-react-app my-app

Comment: try to remove .npm folder: `rm -rf ~/.npm`